# How to find the chart version of subcharts from a released helm chart?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have installed a helm chart with subcharts and I want to find out which version of the subchart is installed. Is there any possible way in helm 3?

Comment: Did you try to pull the chart with `$ helm pull repo/name --untar` and run the command `$ helm dependency list` inside the chart's directory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following official Helm documentation:

- [Helm.sh: Subcharts and globals](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/subcharts_and_globals/)
- [Helm.sh: Charts](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts/)
- [Helm.sh: Helm dependency](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_dependency/)

You can get the version of a subchart used by a chart by following below **example**:

- Download the chart with `$ helm pull repo/name --untar`
- Go inside the chart directory
- Invoke command: `$ helm dependency list`

You can get a message that there are no dependencies:

`WARNING: no dependencies at gce-ingress/charts`

You can also get a message with dependencies and their versions:

```sh
NAME                VERSION REPOSITORY                                        STATUS
kube-state-metrics  2.7.*  https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com/  unpacked
```

Additionally you can check the content of the `prometheus/charts/kube-state-metrics/Chart.yaml` for additional information.

Please let me know if that helped you.

Comment: Thank you, i wanted to know if i could find the chart's version in a released helm chart, but this helped too.